# Reported speech change

Tags: reported-speech, backshifting

- "I was walking down the street this morning **when I saw the accident**"
  If this is changed into indirect speech
- "He told Sam he had been walking down…"

does the part “when I saw the accident” change into indirect speech as well or does it stay the same?

Comment: If _he_ was walking, then _he_ saw the accident, of course.

Answer (score 1):

There is an omitted word "that" that should be between "Sam" and "he", which indicates the shift from non-speech description to indirect reported speech.

The omission is grammatically acceptable, but can lead to confusion such as this.